# How to access VueJS Data from axios request service file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm building an app using VueJS 2 and code below is from `src/utilities/request.js`. This request.js will be loaded from `src/api/usermodule.js` in order to call axios.

**request.js**

```
import atatus from 'atatus-spa'
import store from '@/store'
import { getToken } from '@/utilities/auth'

const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BE,
  timeout: 15000,   // miliseconds
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
  validateStatus: function (status) {
    // return status >= 200 && status < 400

    if(status >= 200 && status < 400) { return true }
    if(status == 429) {
      /**
        *  ########################################################
        *  # I want to set a 'data' variable in App.vue from here #
        *  ########################################################
        */
      return true
    } // Laravel throttle error
    if(status == 419) { return true } // Laravel validation error
  }
})

// request
service.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + getToken()

    return await config
  },
  error => {
    // Do something with request error
    atatus.notify(new Error('Error: ' + error))
    Promise.reject(error)
  }
)

export default service
```

My problem and question is how can I inject/set data into a data() variable inside App.vue so that a proper notification can be send to the user?

Comment: Since you are importing `store`, you could commit something to the store and display it in App.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it after `mounted` phase, something like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    notifs: null
  }
},
mounted() {
  service ... .then(({ data }) => { this.notifs = data })
}
```

But if you want to update data inside this `.js` file, you can use `store`.
After response resolved you can mutate a state, something like this, depending on your code:

```
store.commit('updateNotifs', notifs)
```

Comment: It is not a .vue file. It is a normal .js file that configure axios settings.

Comment: Thank you. Both pxljoy and F.NiX gave me an idea how it can be done - using Vue ```store```